# Sending JavaScript variable to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have to send a value that is stored in a JavaScript variable to a PHP page. The PHP page is in a different folder than the JavaScript page.

This JavaScript variable is in a method that fires when we click a button.

How can I send that variable value to the PHP page?

(This is an Eclipse project.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use jQuery's [POST method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send serialized data to a PHP page that can process your request.

However, you didn't say if you want the client to cache the value and always remind server of the value for all future requests. If so, you can once again use JavaScript to store values inside the cookie, so that every time user click on something (GET / POST) it will also send out the cookie containing your javascript value to the server

Comment: as I think your reply is the most helpful answer.but I in this site they are using mootools.so using jquery is a conflict.isn't it?is it possible to do this using mootools also?

Comment: You can certainly do this with mootool http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML

Answer (score 1):

Using [Ajax](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you submit a HTML form when the button is clicked. If yes then you can set the javascript variable value into a hidden field of the form on button click. After which your PHP code and read its value on the server-side.